# Access VBA creating a query that uses a variant as a where condition

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to write a vba code that will create a query in Access with a where condition based off of the value of a cell from another table. My issue is that when I am trying to pull a string from the varRecords(0,0) Variant it becomes a parameter for the new query and not a string. I tried using cstr() function but it was still becoming a parameter. If I use msgbox to test what is being created it appears as a string. I may have left some stuff out of the code but the basics are below.

```
Dim dbsEmails As DAO.Database
Dim rstEmails As DAO.Recordset
Dim varRecords As Variant
Dim RecordCounter As Long
Dim qdfTemp As QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSQL2 As String

Set dbsEmails = CurrentDb
strSQL = "Select Email, ID from tbl_Email"
Set rstEmails = dbsEmails.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
rstEmails.MoveLast
RecordCounter = rstEmails.RecordCount
rstEmails.MoveFirst
varRecords = rstEmails.GetRows(RecordCounter)

strSQL2 = "Select ID, Stuff from tbl2 Where id =" & varRecords(0,0)

SetqdfTemp = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("Pending Report", strSQL2)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making it a string:

```vb
strSQL2 = "Select ID, Stuff from tbl2 Where id = '" & varRecords(0,0) & "'"
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much.